# AJAX fail error but form is working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a problem... I have a form in WordPress and when i click submit i get error "Ajax failed" but the form is working.

When the user click the submit button it takes like 90 secs of holding and then it alerts "Ajax fail" but submit is proceed and his details are sent.

Can someone help me how to get rid of this?

Thank you,

This is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var old_order_id=false;

$('.btn-st-add-cart').click(function(){
    var me=$(this);
    var data = [];
    var holder=$('.message_box');
    var data1 = $('#form-booking-inpage').serializeArray();
    for(var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
        data.push({
            name : data1[i].name,
            value : data1[i].value
        });
    }
    data.push({
        name : 'action',
        value : 'st_add_to_cart'
    });

    var dataobj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
        dataobj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;

    }

    me.addClass('loading');
    holder.html('');
    $.ajax({
        'type':'post',
        'dataType':'json',
        'url':st_params.ajax_url,
        'data':dataobj,
        'success':function(data){
            me.removeClass('loading');

            if(data.message){
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        type: 'inline',
                        src: me.data('target')
                    },
                    close: function(){
                        old_order_id=false;
                    }

                });
                get_cart_detail(me.data('target'));
            }

            if(data.status){
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        type: 'inline',
                        src: me.data('target')
                    },
                    close: function(){
                        old_order_id=false;
                    }

                });
                get_cart_detail(me.data('target'));
            }

        },
        error:function(data){
            me.removeClass('loading');
        }
    });
});

$('.btn-st-show-cart-modal').click(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
            type: 'inline',
            src: me.data('target')
        },
        close: function(){
            old_order_id=false;
        }

    });
    get_cart_detail(me.data('target'));
});

function get_cart_detail(dom){
    // from 1.2.3
    var dom_div = dom + " " + " .booking-item-payment";
    var me = $(dom_div);
    $.ajax({
        'type':'post',
        'dataType':'json',
        'url':st_params.ajax_url,
        'data': {
            action : 'modal_get_cart_detail'
        },
        success: function(result){
            me.html(result);
        },
        error:function(data){
            // cosole.log("timquen")
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('click','.btn-st-checkout-submit',function(){
    var me = $(this).parents('.booking_modal_form');
    submit_form(me, $(this));
});

//$(document).on('click','.btn_hotel_booking',function(){
//    var form=$(this).closest('form');
//    if(!checkRequiredBooking(form)){
//        return false;
//    }
//
//    var tar_get=$(this).data('target');
//
//    $.magnificPopup.open({
//        items: {
//            type: 'inline',
//            src: tar_get
//        }
//
//    });
//
//});



function do_scrollTo(el)
{
    if(el.length){
        var top=el.offset().top;
        if($('#wpadminbar').length && $('#wpadminbar').css('position')=='fixed')
        {
            top-=32;
        }
        top-=300;
        $('html,body').animate({
            'scrollTop':top
        },500);
    }
}

function setMessage(holder,message,type)
{
    if(typeof  type=='undefined'){
        type='infomation';
    }
    var html='<div class="alert alert-'+type+'">'+message+'</div>';
    if(!holder.length) return;
    holder.html('');
    holder.html(html);
    console.log(holder.offset().top);
    console.log($(window).height());

    if(holder.offset().top>$(window).height()){
        do_scrollTo(holder);
    }
}


function checkRequiredBooking(searchbox)
{

    var dataobj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
        dataobj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;

    var holder=$('.search_room_alert');

    holder.html('');
    if(dataobj.room_num_search=="1"){
        if(dataobj.adult_number=="" || dataobj.child_number=='' ||typeof dataobj.adult_number=='undefined' || typeof dataobj.child_number=='undefined'){

            setMessage(holder,st_hotel_localize.booking_required_adult_children,'danger');
            return false;
        }

    }
    if(dataobj.check_in=="" || dataobj.check_out=='')
    {
        if(dataobj.check_in==""){
            searchform.find('[name=start]').addClass('error');
        }
        if(dataobj.check_out==""){
            searchform.find('[name=end]').addClass('error');
        }
        setMessage(holder,st_hotel_localize.is_not_select_date,'danger');
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

function submit_form(me,clicked){
    var button=clicked;
    var data = me.serializeArray();
    //var data1 = $('#form-booking-inpage').serializeArray();
    //for(var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
    //    data.push({
    //        name : data1[i].name,
    //        value : data1[i].value
    //    });
    //}
    data.push({
        name : 'action',
        value : 'booking_form_direct_submit'
    });
    me.find('.form-control').removeClass('error');
    me.find('.form_alert').addClass('hidden');

    var dataobj = {};
    var form_validate=true;


    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
        dataobj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;

    }
    $('input,select,textarea', me).removeClass('error');
    $('input,select,textarea', me).each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
            form_validate = true;
        }
    });


    if(form_validate==false){
        me.find('.form_alert').removeClass('hidden');
        me.find('.form_alert').html(st_checkout_text.validate_form);
        return true;
    }
    //term_condition
    if(!dataobj.term_condition){
        me.find('.form_alert').removeClass('hidden');
        me.find('.form_alert').html(st_checkout_text.accept_term);

        return false;
    }
    //console.log(dataobj);
    dataobj['order_id']=old_order_id;


    button.addClass('loading');
    $.ajax({
        'type':'post',
        'dataType':'json',
        'url':st_params.ajax_url,
        'data':dataobj,
        'success':function(data){
            button.removeClass('loading');

            if(data.message){
                me.find('.form_alert').addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('hidden');
                me.find('.form_alert').html(data.message);
            }

            if(data.redirect){
                window.location.href=data.redirect;
            }
            if(data.redirect_form){
                $('body').append(data.redirect_form);
            }

            if(typeof (data.order_id)!='undefined' && data.order_id)
            {
                old_order_id=data.order_id;
            }
            if(data.new_nonce)
            {
               // $('#travel_order').val(data.new_nonce);
            }

            var widget_id='st_recaptchar_'+dataobj.item_id;

            get_new_captcha(me);
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert('Ajax fail');

            var widget_id='st_recaptchar_'+dataobj.item_id;

            get_new_captcha(me);
            button.removeClass('loading');

        }
    });

    function get_new_captcha(me)
    {
        var captcha_box=me.find('.captcha_box');
        url=captcha_box.find('.captcha_img').attr('src');
        captcha_box.find('.captcha_img').attr('src',url);
    }
}

$('.payment-item-radio').on('ifChecked',function(){
    var parent=$(this).closest('li.payment-gateway');
    id=parent.data('gateway');
    parent.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('.st-payment-tab-content .st-tab-content[data-id="'+id+'"]').siblings().fadeOut('fast');
    $('.st-payment-tab-content .st-tab-content[data-id="'+id+'"]').fadeIn('fast');
});
});
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: `alert('Ajax fail');` - That's not a *particularly* useful error message you've created there.  What's the *actual error* coming from the server?

Comment: I post my errors guys and a pic as well.. What do you think of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally the problem was in a plugin named AdKingPro... Redudant code inside there.. Just  comment it and work like a charm.